# set office ui fabric datepicker format

Tags: spfx-webparts, fabric

How to set date format in UI-Fabric DatePicker component ?

my code here

```
<DatePicker firstDayOfWeek={firstDayOfWeek} strings={DayPickerStrings}
             placeholder="select date..." />
```

I want date in "dd/mm/yyyy" formate.

Answer (score 5):

Use this for M/dd/yyyy format

```
<DatePicker firstDayOfWeek={firstDayOfWeek} strings={DayPickerStrings}
  placeholder="select date..."
  formatDate={(date: Date): string => {
  return  (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate()  + '/' + (date.getFullYear() );
}} />
```

Comment: It is working, however not like that. I tried it and I had to implement a constant, before I could use it. Here is the link to the solution I found : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70237148/fluent-ui-datepicker-formatdate-date

Answer (score 0):

You can try example from here, check formatDate property https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/DatePicker/examples/DatePicker.Format.Example.tsx